# How to mock a Class<T> Generics object in webclient bodyToMono method

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockito, webclient

I want to mock this webclient post call.
Service

```
fun <T : Any> post(uri: String, body: Any, responseType: Class<T>): Class<T>? {
    return webClient.post()
        .uri(uri)
        .bodyValue(body)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(responseType::class.java)
        .block()
}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception when I am mocking bodyToMono using a Class<T> generic.

ServiceTest

```
@Mock
lateinit var mockWebClient: WebClient

@Autowired
private lateinit var onelinkRestClient: OnelinkRestClient

@Mock
private lateinit var requestHeadersMock: WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec

@Mock
private lateinit var responseMock: WebClient.ResponseSpec

@Mock
private lateinit var requestBodyUriMock: WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec

@Mock
private lateinit var requestBodyMock: WebClient.RequestBodySpec

@BeforeEach
fun setUp() {
    webclient = Service(mockWebClient)
}

val uri = "/path"

`when`(mockWebClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriMock)
`when`(requestBodyUriMock.uri(uri)).thenReturn(requestBodyMock)
`when`(requestBodyMock.bodyValue((requestDTO))).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock)
`when`(requestHeadersMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseMock)
`when`(responseMock.bodyToMono(ResponseDTO::class.java)).thenReturn(Mono.just(responseDTO))
val response = webclient.post<ResponseDTO>("/path", responseDTO, responseDTO::class.java)
```

When running serviceTest, it gives me an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block()" because the return value of "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$ResponseSpec.bodyToMono(java.lang.Class)" is null
```

If I change it from generic Class<T> to a some Class defined it doesn't throw NPE

```
fun <T : Any> post(uri: String, body: Any, responseType: Class<T>): Class<T>? {
    return webClient.post()
        .uri(uri)
        .bodyValue(body)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(responseType::class.java)
        .block()
}
```

Insted of bodyToMono of responseType::class.java, when I do it with defined class, the testcase passes.

eg

```
.bodyToMono(abc::class.java)
```

I am trying to mock a generic class of type T Class<T> in bodyToMono.

Comment: I can't really tell what you're trying to do, but you can't mock a `Class`, and shouldn't.

Comment: Apologies, let me try again. 

I want to mock a .bodyToMono method with a class generic type, which means If I pass if any type of class it should run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your test is correct, but your function is wrong. It calls `::class` on a `Class` instance, so you will always end up with a `Class<Class<?>>`.

Don't you want the following?

```
.bodyToMono(responseType)
```

or perhaps:

```
.bodyToMono(responseType.java)
```

(I don't know Kotlin well enough)